# NoneType not subscriptable

Tags: python

Anyone know why this is returning:

> 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable'?

```py
import requests, json


url2 = "https://xxx.xxxxxx.xx/xxx/xx/xxxxxx"
querystring = {"order_direction":"desc","offset":"0","limit":"5000", "owner": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    }

r = requests.get(url2, params=querystring, headers=headers).json()
for asset in r['assets']:
    if asset != None:
            print(asset['creator']['user']['username'])
```

Comment: Can you post a traceback and the complete error message?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\xxxxx\test.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(asset['creator']['user']['username'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Print(asset) to check what is missing inside. You probably have empty list or element somewhere : 'creator' 'user' or 'username' key missing/not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went and ran the same code, the problem is that one of your asset['creator']['user'] is None

```
{'user': None, 'profile_img_url': 'https://storage.googleapis.com/opensea-static/opensea-profile/14.png', 'address': '0x283af0b28c62c092c9727f1ee09c02ca627eb7f5', 'config': '', 'discord_id': ''}
```

So when you're trying to run `print(asset['creator']['user']['username'])` you try to print `None['user']` which of course returns an error. To fix it change your code to-

```
for asset in r['assets']:
    if asset != None:
        if asset['creator'] != None:
            if asset['creator']['user'] != None:
                print(asset['creator']['user']['username'])
```

Comment: Hey, this fixed the error when running the code with "order_direction":"desc", but when changing it to "order_direction":"asc", the error comes back. Any suggestions?

Comment: I updated the answer, please see if it works

Comment: gotta wait 2 minutes slime (❁´◡`❁)